# Spring restTemplate NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a `NoClassDefFoundError` when using Spring `restTemplate` for the code below at line `messageConverters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());`

What did I miss?

```
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new   ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
    messageConverters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
    restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);
    ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate
                .exchange(
                        "https://abc.stuff.com/abd",
                        HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, String.class);

error:
exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.<init>(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:62)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be missing jackson dependencies. If you are using maven, you might have to add this.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.databind-version}</version>
</dependency>
```

You can also refer to the below link for the complete set of dependencies.

http://www.journaldev.com/2552/spring-restful-web-service-example-with-json-jackson-and-client-program

Answer (score 1):

org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter class is available in spring-web.So try adding below maven dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```